# Can't catch InputMismatchException

Tags: java, exception, inputmismatchexception

So I've been working on an assignment that requires us to build a "Patient manager", that bases which patient to be treated first based on the emergency level. The main issue I'm running into is that when the user enters something apart from a number into the emergency column, it crashes the program and gives me an InputMismatchException, despite with me attempting to catch it. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;

    public class PatientManager {
        private PriorityQueue<Patient> waitingList;

        public PatientManager() {
            waitingList = new PriorityQueue<Patient>();
        }

        // Starter method
        public void start() {
            String choice;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name;
            int emergency = 0;
            int order = 0;
            Patient patient;
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("(1) New Patient.");
            System.out.println("(2) Next Patient.");
            System.out.println("(3) Waiting List.");
            System.out.println("(4) Exit.");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("* Choose an item from the menu:");
                choice = in.next();
                switch (choice) {
                case "1":
                    System.out.println("Enter patient's name:");
                    name = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter emergency [1 (low) to 5 (life-and-death)]:");

                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            emergency = in.nextInt();
                            if (emergency >= 1 && emergency <= 5)

                                break;
                            else {
                                System.out.println("(x) Wrong value. Try again:");
                                emergency = in.nextInt();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("(x) Wrong value. Try again:");
                            emergency = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
                        }
                    }
                    order++;
                    patient = new Patient(order, name, emergency);
                    waitingList.add(patient);
                    System.out.println("Patient added to the waiting list.");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    if (waitingList.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("No more patients.");
                    } else {
                        patient = waitingList.remove();
                        System.out.println(patient.getName() + " is treated.");
                    }
                    break;
                case "3":
                    if (waitingList.size() == 0) {
                        System.out.println("No patients in the list.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Waiting list includes:");
                        Iterator<Patient> iterator = waitingList.iterator();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            patient = (Patient) iterator.next();
                            System.out.println("- " + patient.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "4":
                    System.out.println("Program terminated. Good bye!!");
                    in.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("(x) Wrong choice.");
                    break;
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it happening if you put invalid input in the first time the prompt comes up?

Comment: No. The test I do is first setting a number higher than the limit, then one that's lower, then I attempt a text input(as per the assignment instructions, it shouldn't crash), and that's when I get an input mismatch exception.

Comment: (Edited for better explanation: it happens every time anything apart from numbers are inputed)

Comment: Hint: Simplify you're code.  you are reading into emergency in three different places.  There's no need and it's probably screwing you up.  Just keep the first one immediately after the try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I cleared the result of scanner by just adding in.next() into the catch block. So it looks like this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("(x) Wrong value. Try again:");
                    in.next();
                    System.out.println(emergency);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, your code is much more complicated than it needs to be.  Replace the whole while loop with this then test again.

```
while (emergency < 1 || emergency > 5) {
    try {
        emergency = in.nextInt();
        if (emergency < 1 || emergency > 5)
            System.out.println("(x) Wrong value. Try again:");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("(x) Wrong value. Try again:");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but now it's an infinite loop of (x) Wrong value. Try again:. Even attempting to type while it happens leads to no result.

Comment: @Gabrielp you did change your while(true) to while (emergency < 1 || emergency > 5) right?

Comment: I sure did. It just looks like it's now in a permanent exception throwing loop. It doesn't actually let me type in a new value for emergency.

Comment: @Gabrielp can you try printing out emergency so you can see what it has each time

Comment: I keep getting 0 within the loop. Most likely from the initialized variable at the beginning of the program being 0.

Comment: @Gabrielp I'm not sure what is going on.  The emergency = in.nextInt(); line doesn't seem to be executing for some reason